# How does the SQL Server Fulltext Index grow?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, fulltext-index

I'm trying to get an idea of fulltext index growth and gauge its long-term memory needs.

Does it keep a cache of each search? (Knowing that the first search for a new keywords always takes slightly longer, and is subsequently faster) Will it grow indefinitely?

Or is its size pretty much finite after its creation?

Should I expect performance degradation, stagnation, or improvement over time?

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, a FT catalog will grow proportionally with the number of documents indexed. Caching of FT indexes falls under the general category of SQL Server buffer pool caching.

Have a look at [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Queries on Large Catalogs: Lessons Learned](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917695.aspx)

> Tuning full-text queries on very large
>   catalogs requires some
>   experimentation. We observed that
>   full-text query performance is roughly
>   proportional to the number of rows
>   returned for a given set of search
>   words. We found improvements in
>   performance by using CONTAINSTABLE
>   rather than the CONTAINS function, and
>   by removing unnecessary joins.

Note though that there are *significant* changes in FT performance between SQL 2005 and SQL 2008.

Comment: You probably want to highlight the difference from his question:  it has NOTHING to do with the searches.  If you had a completely static table with an FT index, its size would not change regardless of how many queries were initiated against it.